# Import a .txt file, read it, and assign each parameter of the .txt to a variable on Java

Tags: java, import

I'm currently working on a Java program that needs to calculate the salary of a company. The Java program needs to import a .txt file with the list of workers and another .txt with the amount of deliveries that they've done.

Here's an example file of the workers.txt, where the first is the ID of the worker, the second is the name of the workers and the third one is the level of experience

```
1 : Pedro Reis : 5
2 : Miguel Teles : 5
3 : Nuno Reis : 4
4 : Rafael Carrilho : 3
5 : Nuno Nunes : 3
6 : Osvaldo Pires : 2
7 : Tiago Santos : 2
8 : J. Almeida : 2
9 : Rui Almondegas : 2
10 : Anacleto : 1
11 : José Manuel : 3
12 : Rudolfo Bento : 3
13 : Victor Valente : 1
14 : Lúcia Portugal : 3
15 : Vanessa Santos : 1
```

And here is an example file of deliveries.txt, where the first is the ID of the worker, the second is the area where the delivery was made and the third one is the weight of the package

```
1 : A : 250
2 : B : 610
3 : C : 1250
2 : D : 350
3 : A : 250
4 : A : 500
1 : B : 200
5 : C : 300
5 : C : 250
```

This is a school project and I'm having difficulties on getting the Java program to read the two .txt files and to assign each space of the .txt to a variable.

This is the code I've built

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class project {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("workers.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;

    try {
      fis = new FileInputStream(file);

      bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

      while (dis.available() != 0) {

        System.out.println(dis.readLine());
      }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Now the question is, how can I assign the ID of the worker, the name of the worker, etc etc, to a different variable?

I'm sorry about the long post

Thanks

Comment: Split each line to extract the 3 parts (using `String.split()`, for example), then construct an instance of Worker (which should have 3 fields), and add the instance to a `List<Worker>`.

Comment: Like this?

String string = "1 : Pedro Reis : 5";
String[] parts = string.split(":");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 1
String part2 = parts[1]; // Pedro Reis
String part3 = parts[2]; // 5

Comment: I'm not a Java compiler and virtual machine. Why don't you write that code in a class and test it, instead of asking us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a class like that after you split.

```
class Worker {

    public int id;
    public String name;

    public Worker( int id, String name ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In main class:

```
Map<Integer, Worker> workers = new HashMap<>();
workers.put(*id*, new Worker(*id*, *name*));
```

Example: When you want to get name of worker, you can use following:

```
workers.get(*id*).name;
```